# How to use Azure DevOps artifacts repository as source for DatabricksStep of AzureML?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-artifacts

If we have PyPi Packages added as Artifacts to an Azure DevOps Project Feed, how can we use these packages as a source for installing packages in `DatabricksStep` of Azure Machine Learning Service?

While using `pip` in any environment, we use our Azure DevOps Project Artifacts feed in the following way:

```
pip install example-package --index-url=https://<Personal-Access-Token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<Organization-Name>/_packaging/<Artifacts-Feed-Name>/pypi/simple/
```

The DatabricksStep class of the Azure Machine Learning Service accepts the following parameters:

```
python_script_name = "<Some-Script>.py"
source_directory = "<Path-To-Script>"

<Some-Placeholder-Name-for-the-step> = DatabricksStep(
    name=<Some-Placeholder-Name-for-the-step>,
    num_workers=1,
    python_script_name=python_script_name,
    source_directory=source_directory,
    run_name= <Name-of-the-run>,
    compute_target=databricks_compute,
    pypi_libraries = [
                      PyPiLibrary(package = 'scikit-learn'), 
                      PyPiLibrary(package = 'scipy'), 
                      PyPiLibrary(package = 'azureml-sdk'), 
                      PyPiLibrary(package = 'joblib'), 
                      PyPiLibrary(package = 'azureml-dataprep[pandas]'),
                      PyPiLibrary(package = 'example-package', repo='https://<Personal-Access-Token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<Organization-Name>/_packaging/<Artifacts-Feed-Name>/pypi/simple/')
                    ], 

    allow_reuse=True
)
```

However, `PyPiLibrary(package = 'example-package', repo='https://<Personal-Access-Token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<Organization-Name>/_packaging/<Artifacts-Feed-Name>/pypi/simple/')` will give an error. How exactly should we consume the Artifacts Feed as an input to the `PyPiLibrary` property of the `DatabricksStep` Class in Azure Machine Learning Service?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet below, with a wrapper function around the private package repo string. At least it works for me. If it is not the case for you, could you please provide then what an exact error do you see.

```
from azureml.pipeline.steps import DatabricksStep

def get_pypi_repo_url():
    token = "<your-secured-token-here from a keyvault>" # probably workspace object required
    return f"https://git:{token}@pkgs.dev.azure.com/bla-bla-bla/pypi/simple/"


python_script_name = "<Some-Script>.py"
source_directory = "<Path-To-Script>"

<Some-Placeholder-Name-for-the-step> = DatabricksStep(
    name=<Some-Placeholder-Name-for-the-step>,
    num_workers=1,
    python_script_name=python_script_name,
    source_directory=source_directory,
    run_name= <Name-of-the-run>,
    compute_target=databricks_compute,
    pypi_libraries=[
        PyPiLibrary("azureml.core"),
        PyPiLibrary(
            "example-package", repo=get_pypi_repo_url(),
        ),
    ], 

    allow_reuse=True
)
```